# In Java, how do I replacement a character when the user inputs the phrase and the character to be replaced?

Tags: replace, character, mutation

I'm trying to create code in Java where the user creates (inputs) a phrase, and then picks (inputs) a character.
From there I'm suppose to take the users input and replace the character they picked in to X in the phrase they created. I'm not entirely sure how to create this, I know I'm suppose to use Scanner and then I don't know if I have to create a new string or use a mutation method. It's suppose to look like this when run:

- Enter phrase: Pizza is good
- Enter Character: z
- Pixxa is good

I am fairly new to Java and this is what I have tried so far

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ModifyStrings 
{ 
public static void main (String[] args)
{
String enterPhrase;
    String enterCharacter;

    //Scanner
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner (System.in);

    //Print out that the user will see and type in
    System.out.println("Enter a phrase or sentence: ");
            enterPhrase = scan.nextLine();

    //Second print out that the user will enter in for a character to change
    System.out.println("Enter Character: ");
    enterCharacter = scan.nextLine();

    //mutation
            ?

    //Character changes that letter into x
    System.out.println("New phrase: "+ enterPhrase);
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

this is  simply can be done by using String method replaceAll(). try the code below this will work for you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ModifyStrings { 

    public static void main (String[] args) {   

        String enterPhrase;
        String enterCharacter;

        //Scanner
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        //Print out that the user will see and type in
        System.out.println("Enter a phrase or sentence: ");
                enterPhrase = scan.nextLine();

        //Second print out that the user will enter in for a character to change
        System.out.println("Enter Character: ");

        // This line of code firstly get the string truncate white spaces and then get the first character not all
        enterCharacter =  scan.nextLine().trim().substring(0, 1);

        //Mutation code replace x with your desired character do you want to replaces
        enterPhrase =  enterPhrase.replaceAll(enterCharacter, "x");


        //Character changes that letter into x
        System.out.println("New phrase: "+ enterPhrase);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How would I go about including an error message if the user input a character that was not used in the phrase they made?<br> For example,<br> if they put in J and J was not used it would print<br> "Error: character not in phrase".<br> Would that be a boolean, or a different type of print out? I'm sorry for asking so much.

Comment: @Not_a_bandwagoner you can use contain("") methods of String after getting input character from user and check that character found in given string that will return a Boolean .check the code line below for this solution.  if(enterPhrase.contains(enterCharacter)) {    //Mutation code replace x with your desired              character do you want to replaces           enterPhrase =  enterPhrase.replaceAll(enterCharacter, "x");           //Character changes that letter into x     System.out.println("New phrase: "+ enterPhrase);       }
else {
   //print error message what you want 
}